# Flash Builder 4.5.1 - Developing Android application using FB 4.5 - unable to connect to android device using SDK

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, usb, flash-builder

I created a sample hello world application using Flash Builder 4.5.1 (with the update for iOS and AIR SDK version 2.6) for Android.

It went fine, when creating a new mobile project and run the output in desktop mode  (launch method - as emulator). But when i try to install the app in the device using USB mode, iam not able to do that. Problem is when i launch the application using project run configurations and selecting Launch method as "On Device" , i am not able to get the device in Flash Builder which was connected through USB.

I tried connecting HTC Inspire device and the corresponding driver has been installed. When i try using Java eclipse (Native code), iam able to detect and deploy the code and check. But when i do the same using Flash Builder 4.5.1, iam not able to see the connected devices.

Went through most of the links in the google and found that we need to add the device hardware id in the 'flashbuilder4.5/utilities/drivers/android/android_winusb.inf' file. But after adding the device and restarted FLash Builder, still teh same issue.

Also while trying to solve the issue, i found in most of the links and video that on launch from FLash builder there will be a option for Launch Method "Select Debug via USB" before 'device connection help'(hyperlink). But in the installed version of mine, i didn't able to find the option like that. Do we need to any other update to get the option.

Used Software versions:
1. FLash Builder - 4.5.1 (trial version)

1. AIR SDK 2.6
2. HTC Inspire (android 2.2)

Please let me know, does any one faced this issue before.

Thanks in Advance, 
Regards
Srinivasan.C

Comment: Usually this is a driver issue; but I don't have specific instructions to help fix it.  Have you tried reinstalling the Android USB Drivers from the Android SDK?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I tried uninstalling the driver files of HTC and installed again couple of times. But still the same issue. Then iam  using Flash builder for development and deploying. (not java / android sdk)

Comment: I'm sorry; I was unclear.  I was suggesting that you install the Android USB Drivers from the Android SDK.  More info on how to do that is here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html .  I did not believe that phone specific drivers were distributed with the Android SDK; other than Nexus specific drivers.  But, I thought Flash Builder needed those drivers installed / SDK installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your replies..

I tried in different PC and uninstalled previous version of flash builder (which we have used for testing during preview release). After that, downloaded latest SDK and run the project in Android mobile (HTC - using USB drivers) and desktop it works fine..

The issue in the machine has OS as 'Windows Vista Business' and not able to fix the USB connectivity issue. So i tried in other machine which has OS as 'Windows XP' where i can see the proper installation of USB drivers for HTC and other devices.

Also after proper installation, when we packed and published the project for iOS and Android, it works well in both the platforms without any error.

Thanks,

Srinivasan

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have "USB debugging" enabled in your device ?
Go to "Settings->Applications->Development->Enable USB debugging" . You need to enable USB debugging to run and debug any app on the device.